# CKEditor no me guarda caracteres especiales

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Estoy usando CKEditor version 4 y todo bien pero el problema es que cuando trato de guardar un bloque de código del lenguaje que sea por ejemplo: HTML, C#, JavaScript, Java, etc., no lo guarda en la base de datos, cuando pongo palabras con acentos o con ñ si los guarda.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<script>
function insert()
{
  var editorData = editor.getData();
  var contenido = editorData.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' ');

          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "registrar.php",
          data: "contenido=" + contenido, 
          success: function(data)
          {
            alert("Registro  realizado");
          }         
          });
}
</script>

<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="editor" id="editor" rows="10" cols="80">
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Subir" name="boton" onClick="insert();">
<script>
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
</script>
</form>
```

registrar.php

```
<?php
include_once("class.Database.php");

extract($_POST);
# contenido

$query = "INSERT INTO editor(contenido) VALUES('$contenido')";
Database::insert($query);
?>
```

Estoy usando el archivo config del CKEditor y lo tengo asi

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

    // Simplify the dialog windows.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
    config.language = 'es-mx';
    config.entities = false;
    config.basicEntities = false;
    config.entities_greek = false; 
    config.entities_latin = false; 
    config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;
    config.extraPlugins = 'codesnippet';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'upload.php';
};
```

He usado `config.allowedContent = true;` y nada como podría solucionar esto??

He estado buscando y me he dado cuenta que el caracter & no lo lee ya que cuando se encuentra con ese carácter no pone lo faltante:

Por ejemplo si pongo:
`&lt;` no manda nada pero si pongo `lt;&` manda `<p>lt;`

Entonces creo que el problema es que no puede leer ese caracter, he probado con otros caracteres y si los puede leer.

Ya he probado con poner `config.forceSimpleAmpersand = true;` y `config.forceSimpleAmpersand = false;` y no da solución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno despues de buscar ya que mi pregunta sigue sin obtener respuesta, he encontrado una solución, me di cuenta que ckeditor si toma bien cualquier carácter pero ajax no reconoce el carácter & al realizar el envío a php, lo que tuve que hacer fue escapar ese carácter para no tener problemas con ajax en el envío. Dejo mi codigo por si alguien cuenta con ese mismo problema.

```
<script>
function insert()
{
  var editorData = editor.getData();
  var contenido = editorData.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' ');
  contenido = contenido.replace(/&/g, "%26");

          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "registrar.php",
          data: "contenido=" + contenido, 
          success: function(data)
          {
            alert("Registro  realizado");
          }         
          });
}
</script>
```

Comment: A mi me has arreglado la vida.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por nada @CarlosMolina me da gusto que mi código haya sido de tu ayuda